# How do I create a statistical sample from a record set?

Tags: r

I am using SQL Server 2008 and RGui (64 bit) on Windows 7. I am able to connect to SQL Server from R using RODBC and get the dataset in a variable. Ideally I would like to sample a certain percentage of record set (say 10%) or a fixed number say (25) from the result set directly.

As a stop-gap solution, I am dumping the record set into a file and sampling from there.

Can someone tell, me how to directly sample from the result set.

Code so far:

```
> library (RODBC)
> conn <- odbcConnect ("TestR", "<username>")
> rs <- sqlQuery ("select Col1 from MyTable")
> sampleDocs <- sample (rs, size = 25, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)

> set.seed(100)

> write.table(rs, file="C:\\FromTable.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
> docs <- read.table ("C:\\FromTable.txt")

> sampleDocs <- sample(docs$V1, size=101, replace=FALSE, prob=NULL)
> write.table(sampleDocs, file=\"C:\\\\SampleDocs.txt\", row.names=FALSE,
               col.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: use a query like "Select Col1 from MyTable order by rand() limit 25". You'll have to check your SQL server docs for the _right_ way to do it. But I wouldn't be surprised if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
sampleDocs2 <- sample(rs$ColName, size=10, replace=FALSE, prob=NULL)
```

This would do it!